# pandas grouby count on datetime column based on multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Doctor       Appointment           Booking_ID   No_Show   
  A          2020-01-18 12:00:00     1          0.25
  A          2020-01-18 12:30:00     2          0.28
  A          2020-01-18 13:00:00     3          0.35
  A          2020-01-18 13:00:00     4          0.75
  A          2020-01-18 14:00:00     5          0.65
  A          2020-01-18 14:00:00     6          0.35
  A          2020-01-18 15:00:00     7          0.25
  A          2020-01-19 12:00:00     1          0.25
  A          2020-01-19 12:00:00     2          0.95
  A          2020-01-19 13:00:00     3          0.35
  A          2020-01-19 13:00:00     4          0.75
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     5          0.65
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     6          0.85
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     7          0.35
```

From the above I would like  prepare below Dataframe

Expected output:

```
Doctor       Appointment           Booking_ID   No_Show   Slot_Number     Patient_count
  A          2020-01-18 12:00:00     1          0.25      1               1
  A          2020-01-18 12:30:00     2          0.28      2               2
  A          2020-01-18 13:00:00     3          0.35      3               3
  A          2020-01-18 13:00:00     4          0.75      3               4
  A          2020-01-18 14:00:00     5          0.65      4               5
  A          2020-01-18 14:00:00     6          0.35      4               6
  A          2020-01-18 15:00:00     7          0.25      5               7
  A          2020-01-19 12:00:00     1          0.25      1               1
  A          2020-01-19 12:00:00     2          0.95      1               2
  A          2020-01-19 13:00:00     3          0.35      2               3
  A          2020-01-19 13:00:00     4          0.75      2               4
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     5          0.65      3               5
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     6          0.85      3               6
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     7          0.35      3               7
```

Explanation:

```
Slot_number = 3 means, 3rd slot of that day for that doctor.
Patient_count = 3 means he is the 3rd patient of that day and same doctor.
```

Comment: @jezreal added some explanation. Is that making sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) in lambda function for enumerate variable and for counter is used [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['Appointment'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment'])

g = df.groupby(['Doctor',df['Appointment'].dt.date])

df['Slot_Number'] = g['Appointment'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) + 1
df['Patient_count'] = g.cumcount() + 1
print (df)
   Doctor         Appointment  Booking_ID  No_Show  Slot_Number  Patient_count
0       A 2020-01-18 12:00:00           1     0.25            1              1
1       A 2020-01-18 12:30:00           2     0.28            2              2
2       A 2020-01-18 13:00:00           3     0.35            3              3
3       A 2020-01-18 13:00:00           4     0.75            3              4
4       A 2020-01-18 14:00:00           5     0.65            4              5
5       A 2020-01-18 14:00:00           6     0.35            4              6
6       A 2020-01-18 15:00:00           7     0.25            5              7
7       A 2020-01-19 12:00:00           1     0.25            1              1
8       A 2020-01-19 12:00:00           2     0.95            1              2
9       A 2020-01-19 13:00:00           3     0.35            2              3
10      A 2020-01-19 13:00:00           4     0.75            2              4
11      A 2020-01-19 14:00:00           5     0.65            3              5
12      A 2020-01-19 14:00:00           6     0.85            3              6
13      A 2020-01-19 14:00:00           7     0.35            3              7
```